# Need some help decoding an npm error message from a meteor package installation

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, meteor, npm

I'm trying to install a package for meteor on the command line interface, but I keep getting an error.  I have tried reinstalling node and npm, but error persists.  I have no idea how to proceed.

Here is the message I get in the CLI:

```
USERs-MacBook-Pro:meteor USER$ sudo npm -g install meteor-em

> fibers@1.0.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteor-em/node_modules/fibers
> node ./build.js

gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/Users/USER/.node-gyp/0.10.34"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteor-em/node_modules/fibers/.node-gyp"
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py:873: Warning: 'as' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 11, in <module>
    import gyp
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import gyp.input
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 873
    except ImportError as e:
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:343:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteor-em/node_modules/fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.34
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed
npm ERR! Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "-g" "install" "meteor-em"
npm ERR! node v0.10.34
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! fibers@1.0.1 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.1 install script 'node ./build.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the fibers package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fibers
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/USER/Code/Meteor/npm-debug.log
USERs-MacBook-Pro:meteor USER$
```

Updates:

-Interesting detail: I was never prompted for my password

-found a [discussion thread on the topic](https://github.com/EventedMind/em/issues/3).  Reading through it now:

-just installed [node-gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp)

-also installed [node-fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers)

Comment: 1st question do you have trouble installing other npm packages? Second you should chown the npm location so that you don't use sudo

Comment: 1: Never tried to install any other npm packages.  2: chown?  I'll google it I guess

Comment: Chown means change ownership in your case you need to reclaim ownership of the place npm was installed that way you don't do sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just upgraded from python 2.5.4 to 2.7.9.  I was told that that might help....And it did!

Comment: You can tell Meteor's NPM what Python executable to use by settings the `PYTHON` environmental variable, e.g., `PYTHON=python2.7 meteor`.

Answer (score 1):

I did an "apt-get install -y build-essential" and everything was fine after that ;-)